# Heteroscedasticity or not

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, heteroscedasticity

I run a GLM model with a body condition as a continuous response variable. I included in the model on the explanatory side Pb concentrations (logged continuous variable), Age (2 levels), Sex (2 levels), and Year (2 levels). The results agree with the suspicions, but clear groups are seen on the residual plot (resid vs. fitted) - please see the fig1. I know that the groups represent levels of Age factor (logically, body condition depends on Age). When I don't use this factor in the model, the residual plot looks quite good - fig2.
The question is how such a phenomenon should be understood in fig1. Is it heteroscedasticity or not? What conclusion should be drawn looking at such a figure?
[image]

Comment: your plots seem the wrong way around. Anyway, to check for heteroskedasticity, you could use the plots in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html